# fwknopd on Centos 6.5

Tags: security, centos6

I'm getting the same error as [this guy](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.security.firewalls.fwknop.general/657). Namely,

```
Error: Package: 1:fwknop-server-2.6.6-1.fc21.x86_64 (/fwknop-server-2.6.6-1.fc21.x86_64)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:fwknop-server-2.6.6-1.fc21.x86_64 (/fwknop-server-2.6.6-1.fc21.x86_64)
           Requires: libfko.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:fwknop-server-2.6.6-1.fc21.x86_64 (/fwknop-server-2.6.6-1.fc21.x86_64)
           Requires: libfko >= 2.0.3
Error: Package: 1:libfko-2.0.3-1.x86_64 (/libfko-2.0.3-1.x86_64)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
```

I'm on Centos 6.5 minimal, and I'm these are the packages I'm trying to install:

- https://www.cipherdyne.org/fwknop/download/fwknop-server-2.6.6-1.fc21.x86_64.rpm"
- https://www.cipherdyne.org/fwknop/download/libfko-2.0.3-1.x86_64.rpm"

Unfortunately, looking around the internet, I haven't found any workarounds. Everyone's advice seems to be along the lines of "well, you shouldn't be installing a newer version of glibc", which is eminently unhelpful.

Has anyone else gotten these two things working together?
Would a chroot environment with a different glibc installed specifically for fwknopd be a good candidate / has anyone gotten that to work?

Answer (score 1):

You should install a version of the `fwknopd` package which is built for CentOS 6, rather than Fedora 21.  Sadly, it doesn't appear that the Cipherdyne site provides up-to-date binary RPMs for anything else, so you're stuck with downloading the SRPMs and building them yourself.